# FCNs: Questions about the filter rarefaction in the CVPR paper [Long et al., 2015]

Tags: neural-networks, filters, fully-convolutional-networks

I am reading the [paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Long_Fully_Convolutional_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) about the fully convolutional network (FCN).

I had some questions about the part where the authors discuss the filter rarefaction technique (I guess this is roughly equivalent to dilated convolution) as a trick to compensate for the cost of implementing a shift-and-stich method.

> Consider a layer (convolution or pooling) with input stride $s$, and a subsequent convolution layer with filter weights $f_{i,j}$ (eliding the irrelevant feature dimensions). Setting the lower layer’s input stride to 1 upsamples its output by a
> factor of s.

1. How does setting the input stride of the lower layer to 1 leads to upsampling (and not in the reduction of output dimension)? I am confused about what the terminologies *lower/higher layer* and *input/output stride* refer to here.

> To reproduce the trick, rarefy the filter by enlarging it as
> $f'_{i,j} = \begin{align} \begin{cases} f_{i/s,j/s} & \text{if $s$ divides both $i$ and $j$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \end{align}$
> (with $i$ and $j$ zero-based). Reproducing the full net output of the trick involves repeating this filter enlargement layer-by-layer until all subsampling is removed.

2. I was wondering how the rarefaction defined here leads to the filter enlargement. Based on the equation, it seems that $f$ and $f'$ has the same size, with $f'$ having different filter weights based on $s$.

Comment: I am also unclear on the meaning of this. For (1) my understanding is simply that the stride is reduced from s to 1 which increases the output. I.e., if your stride was originally 4 and you reduce it to 1 then you will increase the output by a factor of 4. I hope someone else answers this.